# Show permission used

Tags: 6, forms, users

I've on a drupal 6 site a custom module which generate a page, i send in that page a form.

When i try to test my form as an anonymous user, it doesn't work as i get:

> You are not authorized to access this page.

I've a `hook_perm` on my module and permission are activate for anonymous user, but that still doesn't work, even after "cache clear" or "rebuild permission".

So i must have another permission in conflict here that forbid me to show my form to anonymous user (as an admin, i can see it). Is there a way for me to print the "rights" that forbid me to access my form, to get a list of the permission used in a specific page?

Comment: Is the path of your form's page under /admin by any chance?

Comment: It might help to also post your hook_menu that is generating the custom page.

Comment: Thx for reply. No i do not use admin in my path, i've also edit my question with the hook_menu.

Comment: I've reformulate the question and found that thread : http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/17214/how-to-debug-permissions with a D7 answer, i need a D6. So i search in that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get an solution : 
Exposed here in : https://drupal.org/node/109157

I had to add '"access callback"   => TRUE' to my hook menu (TRUE because i want anonymous user get access to the page).

```
function custom_createAccount_menu()
{
  $items["createAccount"] = array(
    "title"=>t('Create an account'),
    "page callback"    => "_custom_createAccount",
    "access callback"  => TRUE,
    "access arguments" => array("access createAccount content"),
  );

  return $items;
}
```

and that works.

@SavaryNicolas