# Is there an efficient way to dermine whether a node can be viewed by all users?

Tags: users

I am trying to use the Drupal [node access API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/group/node_access/7) to determine whether a node is subject to an access restriction. That is: I want to make sure that the node can be viewed by *any* authenticated user (provided the authenticated user is granted the right to `view published content`).

The function `node_access('view, $node, $account);` returns `TRUE` if the user object `$account` can access `$node`, and `FALSE` otherwise, so I can get the correct result stored in `$view_for_all` with the following snippet of code:

```
$accounts = entity_load('user');
$view_for_all = TRUE;
foreach ($accounts as $account) {
  if (!node_access('view', $node, $account)) {
    $view_for_all = FALSE;
    break;
  }
}
```

However, looping through all accounts will be very slow if there are, say, 50000 users. I am looking for a *more efficient* way to do this.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of [How to debug permissions?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/17214/how-to-debug-permissions)? Also, if it's supposed to be available to all logged-in users, why not to simply grant permission to authenticated role?

Comment: I say not a dup as this is a specific case and not generic permissions debug.

Comment: @Mołot, no I am not trying to *debug* permissions. This is for a production site. The use case is that I only want to allow a certain field to be populated if there are *no* view access restrictions imposed on the node the field is attached to. I.e. want to check this, and not show the field in the form if there is some sort of access restriction on the node. I don't own the node, so can't know what sort of node access modules the admin has enabled.

Comment: As you both can see, I just asked, not voted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is surely impossible. Modules can decide on the fly which nodes are visible. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7

Answer (score 0):

If you are needing to check node_access records, then you may be able to examine them similarly to how [devel_node_access](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/devel/tree/devel_node_access.module?h=7.x-1.x) does.  In the end, all nodes have grants added to the node_access table, so if there are grants that deny or restrictively add access, then you can probably see it there.

Another option would be to have a dummy account that is an authenticated user, and used as the test case.  This will fail, of course, if you need to detect grant rules that *deny* access to authenticated users who would otherwise be entitled.  It's a sticky situation.

The hardest part about this question is that it seems as though you are looking for a general solution to a specific problem, and I'm not quite sure that a general solution exists.