# Bibliography module url search as anonymous user

Tags: users

I have a problem with the [Bibliography Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/biblio) module and its filter/search functionality.

Via URL it is possible to search for specific keywords:

```
/biblio?f[search]=Smith%2C%20S.
```

would search the publications for Smith, S.

If I am logged into D7 as an admin, this works perfectly. But if I change to another user or log our completely, this is not working anymore and shows me:

> No items found Modify or remove your filters and try again.

I tried to change some permissions, even gave user all the permissions an admin has (just for testing). And it works just, if I enable the ultimate permission:  *Bypass content access control*.

So obviously it is a permission issue. Any ideas, how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you've practically have solve the problem; the issue is with content display permissions. The question need to ask yourself is what access control is being restricted. Is it node type viewable permission? Is it *view unpublished content* permission?

If you're looking for way to troubleshoot this see [How to debug permissions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/17214/how-to-debug-permissions).